# JQuery datepicker suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date picker I use in some of my web applications. Unfortunately, for reasons unknown to me, the date picker suddenly stopped popping up. I have made no changes to this application recently, which suggests to me that it was something environmental. Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


  <script>
      $(function () {

          $("#tb_DateRequested").datepicker({
              dateFormat: "dd M yy",
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              inline: true
          });
      });
  </script>
```

I did some googling, and here is what I tried:

- Changing http to https.
- Adding https in front of my other two links.
- Playing around with different versions of jquery.
- Tried using Chrome and Firefox.
- Made sure javascript is allowed in web settings.

Then I noticed something interesting: I can't actually use the datepicker from the jquery site itself:

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

I'm guess it's some new java security policy that was pushed out, though I'm not sure. Why can I not use the date picker on my own web application or even jqueryui.com?

Comment: The date picker on the jQuery site works for me in Chrome. Sounds like the problem would have to be on your end, but not sure what if it's in multiple browsers. Does the console show any errors?

Comment: Where is the missing `)` after the last `}`?

Comment: Herohtar: Yes, I definitely think it is on my end (I was able to get it working on an off the network laptop). I did not see any console errors, but maybe I'm looking in the wrong place?

Alon Eitan: Not quite sure where you're talking about for the last parenthesis, but I did edit my code a bit down to make my post more readable. I don't think it's an issue with my code.

Comment: I don't see the `)` of `$(function () {`

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing this out! I have edited my post to include this. I apologize - must have forgot it when I copied and edited my code the first time. Unfortunately, this still does not fix my issue as I am unable to utilize the date picker on the jQuery site either.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all your browsers plugins/add-ons/extensions, or just tried to view the site using an incognito/private window?

Comment: Did you switch to `https` maybe?

Comment: When you say you may be looking in the wrong place for console errors where are you looking?

Comment: Alon Eitan-I have always used https. It does not work with http or https. j08691 - I am unable to use incognito/private modes in my environment. Disabling the browser's plugins/add-ons/extensions did not work either.

Comment: In Internet Explorer (the main browser we use, unfortunately), I pressed F12 to open up Developer Tools. Then I selected Console and began clicking in the DatePicker box. I did not see any feedback appear in the box. I said I may be looking in the wrong place, as I am still a novice as far as using Developer Tools to troubleshoot problems and so I worry if I am using it incorrectly.

Comment: Try to load all those resources (js & css) from a different cdn, like https://cdnjs.com

Comment: Alon Eitan - Right, but what about jqueryui.com? I don't think it is anything to do with my code, as I can't access the datepicker from jqueryui.com either.

Comment: They also load the resources from the same cdn like you and maybe it is blocked on your network for some unknown reason